# When I run a GDB/MI session with a command file, can the commands in the command file be parsed as MI commands?

Tags: c, linux, debugging, gdb, gdbserver

I use ngdbmi (a node.js package, which spawns a GDB/MI child process) to control GDB, but sometimes GDB throws a timeout error, and the rsp log is completely worthless.

I doubt that ngdbmi or GDB/MI has bugs, so I first tested GDB/MI and wrote a command file to test GDB/MI, like:

```
$ sparc-rtems-gdb -i mi -x command_file
```

The test passes, but I have a question:

The command file consists of commands like `target remote: 65535`, not commands like `-target-select remote localhost: 65535` (I tried this, but `gdb/mi -x command_file` doesn't identify). Therefore, I can't determine whether when running `sparc-rtems-gdb -i mi -x command_file`, GDB will parse commands to MI commands, or just perform commands as UI commands. (I doubted gdb/mi has bugs, gdb/ui is ok, but now I'm not sure.)